# Why would my WordPress website be so slow?

Tags: mysql, iis, wordpress

### **Goal:**

Make WordPress webpage load faster on local network.  Currently pages load fine but take about 4-5 seconds to load.  I want to cut that down to half the time or smaller.

---

I have a two new VMs dedicated to this new website I'm testing (ON LOCAL NETWORK).  One VM is for the SQL server, and the second VM is for the webserver.

**SQL Server Setup: (less then 50% mem/cpu max)**

- OS: Windows Server 2019
- MySQL: Ver 8.0.29 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

**Web Server Setup: (less then 50% mem/cpu max)**

- OS: Windows Server 2019
- IIS: Ver 10.0.17763.1
- IIS Compression module enabled
- IIS WinCache module enabled
- IIS Output Caching enabled
- PHP: Ver 7.4.29 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2022 16:24:02) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )

**WordPress Setup:**

- Ver 5.9.3
- NO plugins enabled

I currently do not have an SSL cert set up on the server because I want to get these performance issues resolved first.  Was not sure if that would be a factor but thought it wise to mention.

The site loads fine but it just takes forever.  Is there any things that can be checked to see why the site is loading so slow?  Could it be related to mySQL somehow?  It seems that from the default IIS webpage when I put a phpinfo.php page that loads really fast.  Any ideas of tests I could run to troubleshoot slow load times?

Note: I know there are a lot of server admins out there that will knee jerk response with "Don't use Windows it's bad.".  I'm not looking for that kind of "help" here.  I know it runs fine on Windows using IIS.  I have seen plenty of webpages with users saying they have no issues running the sites on Windows with IIS.

Thanks for any suggestions you can provide with a solution or debug help!

Comment: and what is the business related question in here?

Comment: @djdomi What is the business related question?  I was just seeking any suggestions as to why a out of the box new IIS/PHP/mySQL/WordPress setup would be run slow.

Comment: Hi Arvo, I have to agree with Tom I'm afraid - our help pages, which we ask all new users to at least glance over, is clear that we're here for professional sysadmins/system-designers with experience in covering the basics, have done their homework and come to us with information we can use to help - we just get a lot of people come here who want us to guess what their setup is and it gets frustrating - at least you had some detail in your post, just not that much really sorry. Ultimately we want to help but we're not mind-readers, does that make sense?

Comment: I think I found my issue.  A really great suggestion/answer that could have been more helpful is one I found over at spice works.com which suggested that I replace the hostname with the IP address of the MySQL server in my WordPress config.  Having page loads go from 4 second to ~1 second.  I understand this is a professional site @Chopper3 but the way comments are coming off from users, it sounds like server fault is a site that should be a paid membership and have users confirm they are part of the "IT profession".  Why would people who know the answers ask questions here?

Comment: @Chopper3 could you help me learn by telling me what was unclear and left readers with questions?  When you say "we're here for professional sysadmins/system-designers with experience in covering the basics, have done their homework", I'm left wondering what I said in my question that gives you the impression I'm not one of those.  Obviously I have experience as I have stated in my question that I have an virtual environment I have created, setup multiple servers on that environment, set up the mysql server and the webserver, added support for php, installed wordpress, etc.

Comment: Wordpress is commonly used in business, my opinion is this is a valid question. I'm surprised changing the DNS name to an IP helped that much, DNS lookups should be cached. I would suggest looking at Wordpress caching plugins as well, in addition to carefully configured page caching.

Comment: As a complex PHP app itself, WordPress performance tuning requires significant experience with PHP (like using a profiler, like Xdebug). You were just a little bit lucky to find a tip that hits (slow DNS like yours is rare), but in any other case luck might not be applicable.

Comment: Of course this is business related: an individual with money to use WordPress on Windows Server 2019 sounds unlikely.

Comment: he dis still not answer if his page is business environment or relevant. We getting daily WordPress question from enduser which are off topic as Chopper greatly explained. And your comment to me sounds offensive in my feelings. Moreover opinion based questions and answers are also offtopic

Comment: @ArvoBowen  
Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) is a plugin that will help performance of a number of queries, especially those involving `post_meta`.

Comment: @ArvoBowen - One of your sentences from May 9, 2022 - The site loads fine but it just takes forever. Is there any things that can be checked to see why the site is loading so slow? -  Yes there are things to be changed.  If you will provide info requested May 13 at 13:31, suggestions for performance improvement will be provided, complimentary.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I had a HUGE performance increase switching from IIS hosting the site to using a XAMPP setup.  The mysql server is still being hosted on a different box and working smoothly.  But the big change that made everything run so much faster is 1) I switch to mysql MariaDB.  2) Switched to Apache.  3) Switched to Apache/2.4.53.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @ArvoBowen  Great NEWS. After 7 days of uptime, provide Additional Information Requested from your MariaDB server for another improvement in speed of query completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the end for me, the thing that made the biggest impact and made my site load like 10x faster was moving to a XAMPP installation.  The following are some changes that were made in my environment...

1. Switched from IIS hosting the site to using Apache version 2.4.53.
2. MySQL server is still being hosted on a different box and working smoothly.  But was changed to use MariaDB instead of the MySQL standard build.
3. Used WordPress version 6.0.

Hope it helps others.